# Bootstrap 4 Table Align Some Text in Top Right of Table Cell

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple Bootstrap 4 table with 2 columns - I would like to be able to align some of the text in the top right column to the right, whilst leaving the remaining text in that cell left aligned.

Here's my table:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td width=20%>SKU:</td>
    <td width=80%>PM432523
      <div class="text-right">On Special</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Supplier:</td>
    <td>Acme Meat Inc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to get the `On Special` string to be aligned to the right and on the same line as the SKU value - I've tried playing with

and  and  but can't seem to get this to work. I'm not sure if this is even possible or if there's another way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td width=20%>SKU:</td>
    <td width=80%>PM432523
      <span style="float: right;">On Special</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Supplier:</td>
    <td>Acme Meat Inc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 contains a class `float-right` which can be used instead of `style="float: right;"`

Comment: @Akash you right but if  you investigate what is written behind `float-right` class you will see in the css `style="float: right;"`

Comment: Ya sure I understand that, but as per HTML5 standards inline css are not recommended. Although a few usages don't make a big difference but it's a good practice to avoid inline css as the excessive usage leads to bad optimization of the page.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite simple; you just need to replace,

```
<div class="text-right">On Special</div>
```

with

```
<div class="float-right">On Special</div>
```

Find the complete working code below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td width=20%>SKU:</td>
    <td width=80%>PM432523
      <span class="float-right">On Special</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Supplier:</td>
    <td>Acme Meat Inc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.text {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td width=20%>SKU:</td>
    <td width=80%>PM432523
      <div class="text">On Special</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Supplier:</td>
    <td>Acme Meat Inc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change you this code :

```
<div class="text-right">On Special</div>
```

To this code :

```
<div style="float:right;">On Special</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this.

```css
.text-right {
display: inline;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td width=20%>SKU:</td>
    <td width=80%>PM432523
      <div class="text-right">On Special</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Supplier:</td>
    <td>Acme Meat Inc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td width=20%>SKU:</td>
    <td width=80%>PM432523
      <span class="float-right">On Special</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Supplier:</td>
    <td>Acme Meat Inc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```